# Why use DataSource instead of XADataSource?

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource, connection-pooling

As far as I understand there are two types of `DataSource` connections, `javax.sql.DataSource` and `javax.sql.XADataSource`, [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html) explains that `javax.sql.DataSource` give the connection the ability to be pooled and `javax.sql.XADataSource` give the connection distributed transactional behavior.

I understand most `XADataSource` will implement connection pooling as well as distributed transactions so I don't see the point to use a `DataSource` when you could use a `XADataSource` and have both.

Are there any tradeoff when choosing a `XADataSource` over a `DataSource`?

I understand is not mandatory for a `XADataSource` to use pooled connections, is it there a way to find out if a `XADataSource` uses pooled connections or only relying on the `XADataSource` provider's documentation?

---

EDIT:

I am refering to `javax.sql.DataSource` and `javax.sql.XADataSource` because those are the [types `Tomcat 8` factory gives you](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Attributes):

> Type should always be **javax.sql.DataSource** or **javax.sql.XADataSource**
>
> Depending on the type a org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource or a
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource will be created.

I do understand that in the end I would be using a `DataSource` on my code as an API, abstracting the underlying implementation... my question is more related on the decision making process I have to go through when I am configuring `Tomcat 8` (or any other server as well).

I want to have pooled connections and there are many `XADataSource` implementations that will give transactional and pooled connections, so why not always use `XADataSource` if I will get more? (this of course doesn't applies for a `XADataSource` that doesn't implements pooled connections)

Comment: `XADataSource` is used for `two-phase` commits to synchronize the data used by different application instances. I only remember this difference while working on `Oracle ATG Commerce` which uses `JTDataSource` having `XADataSource` under the hoods.

Answer (score 11):

## When to configure `XADataSource`

As explained in the second section, your code will always use the `DataSource` interface (which might use a `XADataSource`). If the question is when should you use a `XADataSource` (eg configure it in your application server), then the answer is simple:

You use an `XADataSource` if you need to have distributed transactions: that is ensure a transaction succeeds or fails across multiple resources (eg different databases).

If you don't need distributed transactions, then you can still configure an `XADataSource`, but this might have some overhead in terms of memory and processing, for example extra objects (eg `XAResource`) that go unused, and maybe in terms of the 'bookkeeping' done by the data source. This overhead is probably negligible though.

Some data source (eg the Tomcat pool as mentioned in your question), can either use a `DataSource` or an `XADataSource` as a factory to create connections (according to the JDBC spec a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` should also be available as a factory, but it looks like Tomcat ignores that option). This doesn't change the way you decide what to use:

1. Don't need distributed transactions:

   Program --uses--> Tomcat connection pool `DataSource` --uses--> JDBC driver `DataSource`
2. Need distributed transactions:

   Program --uses--> Tomcat connection pool `DataSource` --uses--> JDBC driver `XADataSource`

In both cases the connection pool is provided by the Tomcat connection pool `DataSource`, not by the JDBC driver `(XA)DataSource`. A correct<sup>*</sup> implementation of `XADataSource` will not implement connection pooling: that would be the (optional) responsibility of the `DataSource` implementation that uses the `XADataSource` as its factory. So that is not a reason to choose (or not choose) an `XADataSource`.

Your question might stem from the confusing terminology that a `XADataSource` creates `XAConnection` which extends `PooledConnection`. The name `PooledConnection` doesn't mean it comes from a connection pool, it means that after creation these **can** be held in a connection pool (which would be inside the `DataSource` that called `XADataSource.getXAConnection`).

## Responsibilities of `DataSource` and `XADataSource`

In JDBC the responsibility of a `DataSource` is to create connections that can be used by your application. This means that it can be a very basic implementation that does nothing more than go directly to `DriverManager`, but also an implementation that provides connection pooling, and support for distributed transactions.

The idea is that you can swap one implementation for the other, while your code would be untouched.

So, the code consuming connections should always use a `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation. The `javax.sql.XADataSource` (and `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` for that matter) are intended to be used by `javax.sql.DataSource` implementations that provided advanced features like connection pooling and/or distributed transactions. They should not be used directly in your own program. As the tutorial you link says:

> Similarly, when the `DataSource` implementation is implemented to work with an `XADataSource` class, all of the connections it produces will automatically be connections that can be used in a distributed transaction.

In other words `DataSource` is the API you use to obtain a connection, and a `XADataSource` is used by a data source library that provides distributed transaction support. It obtains the `XAConnection`, registers it with a distributed transaction manager, and then gives you the logical connection obtained from `XAConnection.getConnection()`.

This is also a described in the JDBC 4.2 specification, section 12.1:

> Distributed transactions require an infrastructure that provides these
>   roles:
>
> - Transaction manager — controls transaction boundaries and manages the two-phase commit protocol. This typically will be an
>     implementation of JTA.
> - JDBC drivers that implement the `XADataSource`, `XAConnection`, and `XAResource` interfaces. These are described in the next section.
> - An application-visible implementation of `DataSource` to “sit on top of” each `XADataSource` object and interact with the transaction
>     manager. The `DataSource` implementation is typically provided by an
>     application server.
> - Resource manager(s) to manage the underlying data. In the context of the JDBC API, a resource manager is a DBMS server. The term
>     “resource manager” is borrowed from JTA to emphasize the point that
>     distributed transactions using the JDBC API follow the architecture
>     specified in that document.

TL;DR: You --use--> `DataSource` --(potentially) uses--> `XADataSource`

---

*: Historically there has been some confusion in various JDBC implementations regarding responsibilities, and in some cases connection pools have implemented all three interfaces at the same time.

Comment: I'm not sure "as a user of connections" is the most helpful point of view here... I feel like the spirit of the question is more like "why define DataSource instead of XADataSource which seems superior in every aspect"

Comment: @Deltharis I have added a different introduction, but the point stands : `DataSource` is the interface for the 'users' of connections. `XADataSource` is just plumbing that is hidden from you.

Comment: Yeah but, the only workflow in which I encountered the choice between the implementations, is when you're defining data sources in the application server. I have never needed that knowledge when implementing applications themselves, as some part of the technology stack handled the connection itself (and probably always used `DataSource` as you write). Answer to this question in my opinion should tackle the definition side, not the "user of connections" side.

Comment: @Deltharis Ah, I see your point. Let me see if I can address that as well.

Comment: My question is really what @Deltharis is saying...I will clarify it a bit.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel what do you mean by `Contrary to your assumption`? I said is not mandatory for a `XADataSource` to implement pooling, which, AFAICS is the same as you said...or am I missing something here?

Comment: @mFeinstein Your assumption is that an `XADataSource` would implement connection pooling, they don't (or at least: shouldn't); that responsibility would be in the `DataSource` implementation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my assumption is not that they would, but they could (I actually assume most will), I am basing my self on this doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html#deployment_distributed_transactions when it says "In this case, the class com.applogic.TransactionalDS is implemented so that the connections produced are also pooled connections, which will usually be the case for DataSource classes provided as part of an EJB server implementation."

Comment: @mFeinstein The JDBC terminology is slightly confusing here a `PooledConnection` is a thing that **can** be held in a connection pool. The `ConnectionPoolDataSource` (and the `XADataSource`) serve as factories for connections that can be held in a pool, the fact something creates `PooledConnections` (in the tutorial ambiguously called pooled connections) does not imply that at that point it is already pooled (on the contrary). Also consider that the tutorial first shows the use of a basic data source, and then one that provides pooling / distributed transactions.

Comment: @mFeinstein Most connection pool implementations forego the complications of using a `ConnectionPoolDataSource` (or an `XADataSource`), and are just as happy to accept normal `DataSource` implementations, and then wrap connections obtained from that data source in their own variant (or implementation) of `PooledConnection`.

Comment: Hmm interesting, so usually if I need a transactional connection I will have to let go and lose a pooled connection? So I will be choosing between one of them? Is this the case with tomcat?

Comment: @mFeinstein No, and I never said that. Usually data sources that use an `XADataSource` will also provide a connection pool; the Tomcat one does that. Again, it is down to confusing JDBC terminology: a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` is not a connection pool (in some respects a `javax.sql.XADataSource` is a specialization of `ConnectionPoolDataSource`, it just does not extend that interface). Both are (can be) used by a `DataSource` implementation that provides connection pooling and/or distributed transactions.

Comment: So if tomcat's XADataSource provides me with pooling and transaction... Why not just leave it there and maybe I will have a need for transactions in the future... Will it harm my performance or something or am I exaggerating here?

Comment: Tomcat doesn't provide a `XADataSource`, it provides a data source that can use driver `XADataSource` as factory, and as I mention in the first part of my answer, using it when you don't need it might have some overhead, but it is probably negligible.